# Assigning Wordpress post information to PHP array and assign the php array value to javascript array FOR THIS REASON

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, content-management-system

## PHP to Javascript with values from Wordpress

I hope the following code explains what i want.

```
    <?php
    $title = array();
    $i=0;
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    $title[i]=the_title();
    $link[i]=the_permalink();
    $i++;
    endwhile; else:  

    $title[0]="Welcome to my website.";
    $link[0]="/index.php";

    endif; 

    ?> 

    <script>

    var list=new Array();
    list[0]='<a href="<?php echo $link[0] ?>"><?php echo $title[0] ?></a>';
    list[1]='<a href="<?php echo $link[1] ?>"><?php echo $title[1] ?></a>';
    list[2]='<a href="<?php echo $link[2] ?>"><?php echo $title[2] ?></a>';
    list[3]='<a href="<?php echo $link[3] ?>"><?php echo $title[3] ?></a>';
    list[4]='<a href="<?php echo $link[4] ?>"><?php echo $title[4] ?></a>';

    </script>
```

### My need is to

get the latest/popular 5 post title and its permalink

then assign it to the javascript variable like in the above code or better

### Why I need this

Iam creating a simple & working news website wordpress template. And I used a javascript code(got from the web) that will display any text i put inside a specific array variable like a scrolling text( in a flash news/breaking news style).

Now I want the scrolling text to be dynamically updated with the latest blog/news post instead being static like now.

```
    ...
    var list=new Array();
    list[0]='<a href="This is manually typed news one.';
    list[1]='<a href="This is manually typed news two.';
    list[2]='This is manually typed news three.';
    list[3]='This is manually typed news four.';
    list[4]='This is manually typed news five.';
    ...
```

### Reference

The website iam creating currently is temporarily available on this address

[www.iamone.in/todaynewstv](http://www.iamone.in/todaynewstv).

Look at the **Flash News** section - that is what iam talking about.

I got the **complete javascript code** from http://javascripts.vbarsan.com/

### In short, The Output Iam expecting is

To display the latest 5 or 10 blog posts in a scrolling text style without manually updating.

[Sorry for any wrong communication on my side. Hope you people understand my question. ]

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just json_encode the array. Here is an example:

First you get your posts:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'post_status'      => 'publish'
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

Then you json_encode it in a script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function(){
            var postArray = <?php echo json_encode($posts_array); ?>;
            console.log(postArray);
            for (e in postArray) {
                var postInfo = postArray[e];
                console.log(postInfo);
                //how to get the title:
                var postTitle = postInfo.post_title;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The console log will show you which data you can access. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot/Example of json encoded php variable in javascript]