# How to get first or second,.. recent post specifically in wordpress theme and put them in an array for use in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress

Iam creating a theme where i need to work this process.

I tried in many ways and made a number of search/research but failed to find the way.

I asked a similar question before with full details which is at,

[Assigning Wordpress post information to PHP array and assign the php array value to javascript array FOR THIS REASON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046967/assigning-wordpress-post-information-to-php-array-and-assign-the-php-array-value)

Please answer on any of the questions. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning Wordpress post information to PHP array and assign the php array value to javascript array FOR THIS REASON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046967/assigning-wordpress-post-information-to-php-array-and-assign-the-php-array-value)

Answer (score 1):

here is a way to get your posts in many different ways into an array:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => '',
    'category_name'    => '',
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

I think Descending order should make it go from the latest post but if not try Ascending.

As far as getting your php array into a javascript array it can be done with the push method like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var pausecontent = new Array();
    <?php foreach($posts_array as $key => $val){ ?>
        pausecontent.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```

Anyway hope that helps, should work fine but let me know if you run into any complications

Comment: :-(
Thanks for answering. 

I tried this but iam not getting any improvements. 

and my doubt is can we use <?php> inside <script> tag like in your code?

I think the script will try to execute <?php> as a javascript syntax where some errors may occur.

Or if not can u please explain me better how should I use this..?

Comment: Yeah defenitely, I believe it's just you can't send a javascript array into php. But I actually found that as an answer here, though can'n seem to find it now: here is another method:

Comment: oh here is where I found that original answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813580/how-to-assign-php-array-values-to-javascript-array

Comment: oh wait, the post array returns a multidimensional array, that's why it can't just go into a regular javascript array: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts